# auto increment rows that belong to the same group of values

Tags: excel

in a column, i have some values like this:

```
|------------|----------------|
|    false   | abc            |
|            | def            |
|    false   | mpla           |
|            | xyz            |
|-----------------------------|
```

and i need to have all rows from each false row, till the next false value,
in a group, which will auto increment:

```
|------------|----------------|
|    1       | abc            |
|    1       | def            |
|    2       | mpla           |
|    2       | xyz            |
|-----------------------------|
```

which excel formula shoul i try with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just something to note, without any helper row: `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW(A1));FALSE)`. Thought I would put it out there :)

Obviously if your column a contains pure text it becomes: `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW(A1));"FALSE")`

Comment: That's a neat trick. I assume the `COUNTIF` function only evaluates the number of `FALSE` values in the `A` column, for the current row and above.

Comment: @mr.polywhirl, yes it does, hence the indirect to only count up to the current row. A somewhat dynamic range 

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra row before your data (row 1) and then put the formula `=C1+IF(A2="false";1;0)` in the third (C) column.

Answer (score 0):

As Dmitry noted, you can add an additional row at the top and use it to initialize an accumulator at zero. Each time you run into a non-blank cell, you can increment the previous value by 1.

[image: Spreadsheet]

The reason I didn't check for false, is because false is a bit tricky. If you used TRUE instead of FALSE, your formula for row 2 (onward) would be:

```
=$C1+IF($A2=TRUE,1,0)
```

---

I do not have access to Excel at this time, to write a VB script, but I wrote a simple Google script to populate IDs. I am sure you can do something very similar in VB.

Sample Data

```
Group   Name    ID <-- Add third column
FALSE   abc
        def
FALSE   mpla
        xyz
```

You can execute the script to run through the sheet and fill in the ID column.

```js
function autoAassignGroupId() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(),
      rangeData = sheet.getDataRange(),
      lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn(),
      lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow(),
      searchRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow-1, lastColumn-1),
      rangeValues = searchRange.getValues(),
      auto_index = 0;
  for (row = 0 ; row < lastRow - 1; row++) {
    if (rangeValues[row][0] === false) auto_index++;
    sheet.getRange(row + 2, lastColumn).setValue(auto_index);
  }
}
```